# watching the html source after manipulation

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have changed the html source using jquery - added a lot of textfields.
Now when I view the page source using chrome I still see the original source.
Is there a way to view the modified html ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the firebug plugin of firefox and right click > select all, then right click again "show selected source". Or you can simply right click on the changed element of your page > "inspect element"

Answer (score 1):

Use the Developer Tools menu option to see a serialisation of the in-memory DOM.

The source isn't being modified. It is the *source*.

Comment: "The source isn't being modified. It is the source." So it must have a state then. It now shows 5 fields where as the source shous one.

Answer (score 1):

The View source in all browsers, will always show you the base HTML of the document as it was loaded..

To see updates to the DOM, in chrome you need to use the Developer Tools feature...  (ctrl+shift+i)

In firefox, I personally use the firebug plugin...  And for IE: I don't test in IE so I don't know what's available there...

If you want a video on how to use the developer tools, I'll get you one.